# DB2 -Clause IN-Multiple Value

Tags: sql, database, db2

The following code is working fine when the column 'generated_key ' return one value

WHERE code IN ( SELECT generated_key FROM List_agg )

| CODE | generated_key |
| --- | --- |
| EU00100ST10000016 | EU00100ST10000016 |

But when the column generated_key containt more than a values, it return 0 rows

| CODE | generated_key |
| --- | --- |
| EU00100ST10000016 | EU00100ST10000016, EU00100ST10000017 |

Comment: Is “SELECT generated_key FROM List_agg” returning multiple records or a single record containing multiple values?

Comment: it return a single record that contain multiple values separeted with a comma

Comment: OK - that won't work then. IN is expecting a list of object names but what you are passing it is a string. Can you write a SELECT statement that returns a list of the code values you want (i.e. multiple records)? e.g. WHERE code IN ( SELECT DISTINCT code FROM some_table )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to compare to a list, use delimited comparisons

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM list_agg
              WHERE ',' || generated_key || ',' LIKE '%,' || code ',%' 
             )
```

The "list_agg" name suggests that you are aggregating values from another query.  If so, you might be able to use use `in` with no aggregation.  But your question doesn't have enough details to know if that is really the case.

Comment: list_agg is created like this : with List_agg AS (select  'EU' AS instance,LISTAGG(CAST(instanceCode AS varchar(1024)),',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY instanceCode) AS generated_key FROM table1 GROUP BY instance)

Comment: Thank you Gordon, its working like you said. but i dont understand why its not working with a simple in . if you can explain to me . best regards

Comment: @PTC86 . . . Because of the comma-delimited string returned by `LIST_AGG()` is a single string value, not a list of separate values for comparison.

Comment: maybe it's a dumb question, but how can i convert the result returned by LIST_AGG() to a list separate of values?

Comment: @PCT86 . . . Don't use `LIST_AGG()` just use `IN` or `EXISTS` with a subquery.